# Error when finding the total depth of a binary tree

Tags: python, binary

I want to test the total depth of a binary tree, so I wrote the following code:

```
    def nodeDepths(root):
        return depthSum(root, 0)
        
    def depthSum(node, depth)
        if node.left:
            depth += depthSum(root.left, depth+1)
        if node.right:
            depth += depthSum(root.right, depth+1)
        return depth
        
    # This is the class of the input binary tree.
    class BinaryTree:
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
```

I then encountered the following error, please let me know how to fix this.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 7, in 
import json_wrapper
File "/tester/json_wrapper.py", line 3, in 
import program
File "/tester/program.py", line 4
def depthSum(node, depth)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, read the error :P.  You have a syntax error on line 4 and your missing a `:` on the end of your def.

As for your algorithm, not really sure why you have the `nodeDepths` function, it's not really helping.

For your `depthSum` function, right off the bat, your algorithm will never complete as you are stuck in an infinite recursive loop - you never actually traverse the tree due to using `root` instead of `node` in your depthSum function.

Take a look at this, it's a simple way to check the depth:

```py
def traverse(root, depth=0):
    if root:
        return max(traverse(root.left, depth+1), traverse(root.right, depth+1))
```

and just call it directly, with

```py
traverse(root)
```

I don't see a use case for the nodeDepths function.